# Conversion between binary and decimal

Tags: unix

How do I convert between decimal and binary? I'm working on a Solaris 10 platform

> Decimal to Binary
> 4000000002 -> 100000000000000000000000000010
>
> Binary to Decimal
> 100000000000000000000000000010 -> 4000000002

I used the following command in unix but it takes lot of time. I have 20 million records like this

For decimal to binary, set obase to 2:

```
echo 'obase=2;4000000002' | bc
```

For binary to decimal, set ibase to 2:

```
echo 'ibase=2;100000000000000000000000000010' | bc
```

Comment: What is the range of the numbers?  Is it larger than 32 bits?  64 bits?  If not, then you can write a C program to do the job which is less general than `bc` and hence can be faster.  There isn't a binary output option in standard C `printf()`, which is a nuisance, but hardly insurmountable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running `bc` once for each number that will be slow.
Can you not arrange for the data to be delivered to a file and input in one go?

Here's a simple illustration, starting with your numbers in the file called input.txt:

```
# To binary
$ ( echo 'obase=2;ibase=16;'; cat input.txt ) | bc | paste input.txt - > output.txt

# To hex
$ ( echo 'obase=16;ibase=2;'; cat input.txt ) | bc | paste input.txt - > output.txt
```

The results are written to the file output.txt.

The `paste` is included to produce a tab-spearated output result like

```
07      111
1A      11010
20      100000
2B      101011
35      110101
80      10000000
FF      11111111
```

showing input value versus output value.
If you just want the results you can omit the paste, e.g.:

```
$ ( echo 'obase=2;ibase=16;'; cat input.txt ) | bc > output.txt
```

Note that you probably have to set `ibase` as well as `obase` for the conversion to be correct.
gclswceap1d-mc48191-CRENG_DEV [/home/mc48191/scratch]

Comment: Hi can u explain me what is FOO represents

Comment: @user446069 - I've updated the answer.  For background on FOO in the original posting see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document - it was just a here document terminator.